# Changing the look and feel (like 3d effect) of grids in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to change the look of the data grid in silverlight (or any other object), by look i mean changing the depth or the effect of it so it looks 3d like and stands out?

Thanks,
Michelle

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style of any object in Silverlight.
Search for Styles in Silverlight...

You can change the style for all controls of a certain type in your application or in a part of it.  You can also change specific controls.

You can change the style conditionally (in function of the state, responding to a trigger etc.)

[ScottGu's basic tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-4-using-style-elements-to-better-encapsulate-look-and-feel.aspx)

[Links to further reading](http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/02/styles-in-silvelrlight-everything-a-developer-needs-to-know)